# How do I keep dirty state in EditText under the MVP pattern?

Tags: android, mvp

I use the MVP pattern.

In my Activity onResume() I call the Presenter which calls the Model, data is loaded and my Presenter call my Activity (View) and updates my EditText fields.

Now if I change my EditText and call another Activity, come back to the original Activity my data is reloaded (due to onResume()) and my dirty data is gone.
How do I handle this scenario best under the MVP pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Activity are doing this process to initialize:

onCreate -> onStart -> onResume -> Running

If you open another activity:

Running -> onPause

And when you close the other activity:

onPause -> onResume -> Running

As you can see, when the other activity is closed, you will go to onResume another time.
If you need to initialize your EditTexts, I think that is better to do at onCreate. In this way, you don't lose your data.

Comment: onCreate() is only run once when the Activity is created. I'd like to load my data every time in onResume() but not when there is dirty data.

Comment: please, can you explain what is dirty data?

Comment: I load something via onResume(), then change a value manually in an EditText field, i.e. the data is changed. Your solution is not wrong, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: And what is the ultimate solution?)